# Element locator issues: `("css", ".dialog")` vs `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dialog")`

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, wait

I've had to migrate some code at work from using `("css", ".dialog")` locators to `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".dialog")`.  The former worked on selenium-python 2.35.0 and the latter has been tested to work on 2.35.0, 2.37.0 and 2.39.0.

However, some Googling around hasn't turned up *why* the locator using "css" does not work anymore, why it used to work or whether it was ever supposed to work.

Could someone shed some light on this?